# Why does Bash escape colon when autocompleting a filename?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

When I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> in Bash so that  it autocompletes a filename that contains a colon, the result of autocompletion escapes the colon. E.g. starting with the following (without executing the last line),

```
touch a:b
ls a
```

I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and the result is

```
ls a\:b
```

But it doesn't seem to affect anything when I just issue `ls a:b`. The result is the same as for `ls a\:b`.

So why does Bash escape the colon? Does it have special meaning in some cases?

Comment: I'm sure it has _something_ to do with rcp/scp style `host:/path` addresses, but I have no idea why the backslash would have any effect related to that.

Comment: In that case, no, but in other cases the colon could be confused as  a PATH separator.  bash is probably escaping it in all cases to be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colon is one of the characters in
[COMP_WORDBREAKS](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html):

> **COMP_WORDBREAKS**
>
> The set of characters that the Readline library treats as word
> separators when performing word completion. If COMP_WORDBREAKS is
> unset, it loses its special properties, even if it is subsequently
> reset.

As explained in
[Completion Items Starting With Colon Character](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bash/2014-08/msg00004.html):

> The colon breaks words for the completion system (look at the
> description of the COMP_WORDBREAKS shell variable), so when you type
>
> ```
> progname :[TAB]
> ```
>
> the completion system gets an empty word to complete. If all of the
> possible completions have `:' as the longest common prefix, then the
> completion system will insert the colon into the line.

Removing the colon from the COMP_WORDBREAKS environment variable
will solve the problem.

See for example
[Bash completion for Maven escapes colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805412/bash-completion-for-maven-escapes-colon).